# Entity Framework Core SaveChanges doesn't update records

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am getting a row of a entity out with linq and modifies it. But `SaveChanges()` doesn't update it for some reason.

```
foreach(Kontraktdto k in Kontrakt)
{
    var kontrakt = context.LkKontrakter.FirstOrDefault(x => x.KontraktId == k.KontraktId);

    if (kontrakt == null) 
        continue;

    var entry = context.Entry(kontrakt);
    entry.State = EntityState.Modified;

    kontrakt.OpsjonBetingelse = k.OpsjonBetingelse;
    kontrakt.OpsjonVarslingsdato = k.OpsjonVarslingdato;
    kontrakt.Opsjon = (double)k.Opsjon;

    entry.Property(e => e.OpsjonVarslingsdato).IsModified = true;
    entry.Property(e => e.OpsjonBetingelse).IsModified = true;
    entry.Property(e => e.Opsjon).IsModified = true;

    context.LkKontrakter.Update(kontrakt);
}

context.SaveChanges();
```

I have tried to set the `Update` method up, each property as `IsModified = true` and to set the `EntityState` to `Modified`.

I would really like some help on this problem.

Comment: "But `SaveChanges()` doesn't update it for some reason." What does it do? You shouldn't have to set `EntityState.Modified`if you're changing properties on an object pulled from the database with the same Context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm seeing a lot of code that isn't necessary.  Try this...

```
foreach(Kontraktdto k in Kontrakt)
{
    var kontrakt = context.LkKontrakter.FirstOrDefault(x => x.KontraktId == k.KontraktId);

    if (kontrakt == null) 
    {
        continue;
    }

    kontrakt.OpsjonBetingelse = k.OpsjonBetingelse;
    kontrakt.OpsjonVarslingsdato = k.OpsjonVarslingdato;
    kontrakt.Opsjon = (double)k.Opsjon;
}

context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: This will save each entity separately. The SaveChanges can/should be moved outside of the `foreach (...) { ... }`

Comment: @Maarten I admit I'm very new to Entity Framework.  If the save was moved outside the loop, would update be required inside the loop?

Comment: @Archer No, it wouldn't. It maintains an internal state of any objects that it is aware of that need to change in the database.

Comment: @Archer No. The entity instances are tracked by the context, so the update would not be required.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I've updated the answer in that case.  I'm sort of using other people's questions to force myself to learn more, so I appreciate the help :)